# XCode 4.6 shows a warning of memory leak for method + (void)beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context;

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

This question here [Iphone - how to pass a parameter to animationDidStop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297354/iphone-how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-animationdidstop) puts up the whole question in context. According to the best answer there, I was releasing the context in my animationDidStopSelector. But since I updated my Xcode, I am getting this warning

```
 - (void) helloThere: (int) myValue {

  // I am trying to pass myValue to animationDidStop
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.view.frame.origin.x]]; //Warning raised on this line
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
  [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

  // do stuff
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {

  CGFloat usesThisValue = [(NSNumber *) context floatValue];
  [(NSNumber *) context release];
}
```

And the warning in the log says:

```
warning: Potential leak of an object       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.view.frame.origin.x]]; //Warning raised on this line
 1 warning generated.
```

Is there a solution for this? And if not, how can I shut this warning for my project?

Comment: That isn't enough information!  Where is the leak?  Please show more code and more output from clang/instruments.

Comment: Hope I explained the question much better now.

Comment: Does it still complain if you use a `CFNumberRef` instead of an `NSNumber*`?

Comment: @Richard Creating a CFNumberRef again requires me to have a pointer to the value. This way it becomes similar to the "malloc method" in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2297483/1685709 . Thus, the same warning is regenerated.
Though since I haven't worked much with CFNumberRef, I might be doing it wrong altogether. Could you provide with an example of what you are trying to put up?

Comment: Did you try to run static analyzer "Analyze" - without launching instruments?

Comment: `begin / commitAnimations` is an ancient API from pre iOS4, you should be using the block based UIView animation methods instead.

Comment: @Abizern I know we are a bit behind, but that ain't a priority task right now. This is why I asked in my question, for a suggestion to shut this warning up.

Comment: In which case the suggested solution of putting the context value in an iVar that you can release on dealloc is a valid one. But shifting to the modern block based animation methods make this a lot easier, as the objects can manage lifetimes of objects that it uses.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are allocating an NSNumber inside this call. The number is not being released. Try changing this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.view.frame.origin.x]];
```

**Edit**
[Here is a link to a post about handling the (void *)context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5189273/1144161)

So you need some way to keep a reference to your NSNumber that can be cleaned later.

```
self.contextNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:self.view.frame.origin.x];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:self.contextNumber];
```

and clean it in your dealloc

Comment: -1 It is not safe to use an `autorelease` object as a `void *` because we have no guarantee over its lifetime.

Comment: (Because this 'object' is used in a callback later, we don't know whether the object was deallocated (almost certainly) and its memory reused.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction @Richard. You are correct, I was just looking at how the argument was being passed not to what it was being passed to.

Comment: @Jaybit Wouldn't it be more intelligent to pass context as nil? You are creating another property for something that can anyway be accessed by another property.

Comment: I have never needed to pass anything other then nil. I am just trying to explain what the leak and warning is about and how to solve it with what you have provided.